# Representing the ratio of two expressions in one chart in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I want to represent the ratio of two qlikview expressions that i'm getting from the database and i want it displayed on one chart as two different bars. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking for, but you can create a compound expression from two prior ones pretty easily. If you've labeled them "Expression 1" and "Expression 2", then you would just reference those labels to calculate your ratio:

[Expression 1] / [Expression 2]

For the axis, what you're describing sounds like the "Split Axis" property on the chart's "Axes" tab.